# How to change the value of a reference contained inside a list?

Tags: python

In python how can i change the value of references contained inside a list ? 
For example in the following code

```
x = 'stack'
y = 'exchange'
l = [x,y]
l[1] = 'overflow'
```

The last line would actually replace `y` with `'overflow'` but what I want to do is change the reference contained at `l[1]` to `'overflow'` how can I achieve the same ?

PS : `y = 'overflow'` is not an accepted answer :P

The context probably will make the problem clearer there are 50 variable that I have inside a list initialised to zero and I want them to set their values at run-time.so that when at a later point of time I do a print variable50 , i get the new value not zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do rebind reference at `l[1]` to `'overflow'` with `l[1] = 'overflow'`. If you want to actually modify the string object, you can't. Strings are immutable.

Comment: ... and if you want to change it another way, you can't either. References are treated as values.

Answer (score 4):

"change the value of references" is awkward phrasing and there are two separate things that I can imagine that you mean:

1) cause the element of the list to refer to something else; but that's what your example does and is what you say you don't want.

2) cause the referred-to element of the list to change. The referred-to element is an object, so this is only possible by invoking code that changes the object's state. Python's `str` type is immutable, so no such code exists for the example situation.

What are you **really** trying to do? Idiomatic Python code embraces reference semantics rather than trying to fight them.

Comment: what i am trying to do will make the value of y change to 'overflow'

Comment: ... That's not what I asked. What are you **really** trying to do?

Comment: I just update the question with the context hope it makes it clearer

Comment: ... That doesn't really make any sense. Why not just use the list instead of the variables, especially if they have names like 'variable50'? If they're actually separate, meaningful variables, then (a) why put them in a list and (b) why not set their values by, you know, setting their values?

Comment: yes they have meaningful names,not like variable 50 but their value needs to be set according to a logic that is determined at the run-time.

Answer (score 1):

You want to add a new element to your list and sort it on position 1? That can be achieved with basic list functions.. Just a question why aren't you using dictionaries?

Answer (score 1):

Is this interesting ?

```
x = 'stack'
y = 'exchange'
z = 'overflow'

l = [x, y]
l
['stack', 'exchange']
```

use python's swap

```
y, z = z, y
```

but then, you have to re-assign the list

```
l = [x, y]
l

['stack', 'overflow']
```